# Application Insights E_ACCESSDENIED exception, where to look?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have started to getting this (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) filling up my Application Insights for a ASP.NET MVC app published to a Azure App Service
Since there is no trace to my code in the stack trace, I can't figure out where it happens.

The only event that happens right before is this "StopProfiler triggered" Trace event (which is not mine)
[image]
Somebody has any idea?

**Exception properties**

> - Event time: 7/15/2018, 2:06:30 PM
> - Message:    Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
> - Exception type: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
> - Failed method: DiagnosticsHub.StandardCollector.Host.Interop.IStandardCollectorService.CreateSession

**Custom Data**

> - AgentVersion    2.4.60615.1
> - AgentSession    e578e3ef-238b-496d-b4f1-928321a8c405
> - MachineName rd00155d523178
> - Description StartProfiler failed.
> - RunningMode Antares
> - Source  ApplicationInsightsProfiler

**Call Stack**

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
>      at DiagnosticsHub.StandardCollector.Host.Interop.IStandardCollectorService.CreateSession (ApplicationInsightsProfiler, Version=2.4.60615.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>      at Microsoft.ServiceProfiler.Collectors.StandardCollectorService.CreateSecureSessionWithAgent (ApplicationInsightsProfiler, Version=2.4.60615.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>      at Microsoft.ServiceProfiler.Collectors.StandardCollectorBase.InitializeCore (ApplicationInsightsProfiler, Version=2.4.60615.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>      at Microsoft.ServiceProfiler.Collectors.DetailedTraceCollector.StartMonitor (ApplicationInsightsProfiler, Version=2.4.60615.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
>      at Microsoft.ServiceProfiler.Agent.Orchestration.Orchestrator+d__15.MoveNext (Microsoft.ServiceProfiler.Agent.Orchestration, Version=2.4.60615.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in latest release. Try to upgrade to 2.6.5.

You can run an update from [WebApp Extensions Blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW07B.png)
 or from [Application Insights Enablement Blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zm5y8.png)